# Json file name and call

Tags: html, angularjs, json

Hi I have a simple problem with angular and JSON.

First of all there are two JSON file with same "systemCode" in all object.
http://jellywesite.esy.es/db/
subCat.json and category.json

Has you can see in this lines

> "systemCode": { "Key" : "1201", "open" : false },

I'm try with ng-show change the open to true 
and call for the info in sub_cat Json.

[This is the INDEX and Controller.](https://gist.github.com/yaghobieh/aad9b77a8e5351345dd3a69b25c68147)

line 46

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="subCat.systemCode.open" />
```

and LINE 71 ng-show

I think the problem is beacuse the systemCode don't know the Key

Please help me to solve it

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do ? I do not understand what you mean by trying to change the `open` attribute with `ng-show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are trying to change the boolean value that is inside the `open` attribute in your arrays and have it decide whether the line will be shown in your `<a href="table.html"...`.

If that is the case then I see what your problem is. In your checkbox input, you are changing the `open` value from the `cats` array. But you are displaying the `sub_cats` arrays in your list of links. The two objects have no control over one another, they are completely independant.

What you need to do is replace your input :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="subCat.systemCode.open" />
```

With

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="handleChange(subCat)" ng-model="subCat.systemCode.open" />
```

And in your controller add the function definition as follows :

```
// handles the checkbox change event
$scope.handleChange = function (subCat) {
    // copy your open status from the cats to the sub_cats
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sub_cats.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.sub_cats[i].systemCode.key === subCat.systemCode.key) {
            $scope.sub_cats[i].systemCode.open = subCat.systemCode.open;
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: In the console
I'm use ng-click and it's worked but didn't give me the right result in the circle show

Comment: If you are using `ng-click` in your checkbox input, please change it back to `ng-change` as I suggested above.

Comment: Does it give you a different error ? Does something different happen ? Can you add a `debugger` or a `console.log` to the `handleChange` function to see if it is being executed ?

Comment: I'm add 
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="handleChange($event, subCat)" ng-model="subCat.systemCode.open" />

And it's giving me another Error 
read property 'target' of undefined
    at b.$scope.handleChange (ctrl.js:19)

Comment: Can I give you the FTP account?

Comment: No need, I updated my solution, please try again. What I did is basically pass both `ng-change` and `ng-model` and in the handler function we simply need to copy the checkbox status to `sub_cats`, let me know if it works or the new error.

Comment: ok try the following :

    $scope.$watch(
        function () {
            return $scope.sub_cats;
        },
        function(newVal) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(newVal));
        }
    );

Paste here the last log before you click the checkbox and the one right after you click it.

Comment: Ty, you really help me
The problem was in Ke y and not key

Comment: Oh I see, the problem can be sneaky sometimes, you are welcome :)

Comment: One more quesiotn, If i close the Menu it's show some buble.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you create another question explaining the new issue in detail then send me the link here ?